# Casting Oddities in VB.Net

Tags: .net, vb.net, casting

So I was working with some code that required a cast from a `BigInteger` retrieved from a `Dictionary` to a `Long`. I originally had it written on a single line like this:

```
Dim Length As Long = If(Dict.ContainsKey("key"), CLng(Dict("key")), 0)
```

This always gave me an error saying that the conversion from `BigInteger` to `Long` was invalid. Nothing seemed to fix the problem, until I spaced things out.

Full Error:

```
System.InvalidCastException was caught
  HResult=-2147467262
  Message=Conversion from type 'BigInteger' to type 'Long' is not valid.
  Source=Microsoft.VisualBasic 
  StackTrace:
   at Microsoft.VisualBasic.CompilerServices.Conversions.ToLong(Object Value)
   at CMIS.CmisImport.RegisterResult(String BaseTypeId, Dictionary`2 Props) in C:\Source\Main\CMIS\Import Export\CmisImport.vb:line 265
   at CMIS.CmisImport.ProcessResult(IObjectData Result) in C:\Source\Main\CMIS\Import Export\CmisImport.vb:line 91
   at CMIS.CmisImport.RunOperation() in C:\Source\Main\CMIS\Import Export\CmisImport.vb:line 65
   at Core.ImportProvider.StartOperation(Boolean ImportBatch) in C:\Source\Main\Core\Support Classes\Import-Export Providers\ImportProvider.vb:line 140
   at Core.frmProviderImport.Worker_DoWork(Object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e) in C:\Source\Main\Core\UI\Forms\frmProviderImport.vb:line 164
 InnerException:
```

This:

```
Dim temp as BigInteger
If (Dict.ContainsKey("key")) Then
    temp = Dict("key")
Else
    temp = 0
End If

Dim Length As Long = CLng(temp)
```

Somehow achieves the behavior that I want, but I can't seem to figure out why `CLng` failed when it was on one line. I just want to know why the first line of code failed, when the second one succeeded.

Comment: please include the full error message to better illustrate your description.

Comment: I can't reproduce your error.  Both versions work for me.

Comment: Why wouldn't you have declared your dictionary as `Of String, BigInteger` ?

Comment: Please don't edit the question to include a solution. If you have a solution to your problem, remember that you can always [answer your own question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For those who cannot recreate the error, the cause is:

```
Dim dict As New Dictionary(Of String, Object)
```

If the dictionary's value is **Typed** then no error occurs, however if it's Object then the real type is late-bound and somehow causes this error.

The only circumstance I can think of where this would be happening 'in real code' would be using old fashioned deserialization, where you often juggle dictionaries of (object,object) while assuming the types. It seems for BigInteger to Long, some explicit conversion is required.

Perhaps somewhere deep in the system.numerics library there is a Narrowing conversion but no Widening conversion.